# Non-POD object with common linkage: what's supposed to happen?

Tags: c++

Someone here wrote the following, at file scope:

```
std::auto_ptr<ClassWithDestructor> an_auto_ptr;
```

They *meant* to add `static` but neglected it.

Then, two different linux shared libraries, each containing the .o containing this declaration, ended up linked to an executable.

The `auto_ptr::~auto_ptr` for this item ran twice, with unfortunate consequences.

Is this defined behavior, undefined behavior, or a gcc+ld bug?

Comment: What does that have to do with Fortran?

Comment: Declarations with neither extern nor static are 'Fortran common'. At least to us old farts. If it proves too distracting, I'll remove the word 'fortraN'.

Comment: It is distracting and misleading. Such declaration do not work like Fortran common blocks at all.

Comment: How do you see them as different from fortran?

Comment: In Fortran common blocks are merged into one memory area. C++ has One Definition Rule which prohibits such things.

Comment: Yes, but the point here is that the linux linker is making ONE MEMORY AREA behind the back of C++. The underlying storage mechanism is fortran common, even if the C++ language is trying to prevent it.

Comment: "linux linker is making ONE MEMORY AREA" -- this is precisely NOT what happens.

Comment: -fno-common specifically references 'common blocks' which is a fortran term. QED - without -fno-common, you get fortran behavior.

Comment: You may or may not get Fortran behavior for **C** with gcc depending on `-fno-common` You do not get fortran behavior for C++ with or without `-fno-common`. Try it for yourself, look at the assembly code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration is also a definition. You have two definitions for the same object in a program. This is a violation of One Definition Rule and thus Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Even in separate shared libraries? Wouldn't you just get two totally distinct objects? I agree with you that if both of these files were linked into the same library, it would definitely violate the rule.

Comment: If they were in the same library, you would just get a "duplicate symbol" linker error. With shared libs, all symbolic references in *both* libs are resolved to the first one that loads. So the second lib only sees the definition from the first one -- but the ctor/dtor code still runs twice. Now there's a way to make each lib to try to resolve within itself first -- use -Bsymbolic flag to the linker *at library creation time* (but it's not recommended and I suppose it's simpler to recompile).

Comment: Please elaborate. If in an ordinary executable you used this (no extern, no static), is C++ calling upon the linker to give an error, even though it's perfectly valid C? Can you link to the rule?

Comment: This is not required by the C standard, and is outright forbidden by C++. Some C compilers (particularly on Unix) accept such multiply-defined *uninitialized* globals as a language extension, others do not. See gcc's `-fno-common` option documentation.